# Nodejs CANNOT GET

Tags: node.js, get

I've been trying to do a route in Express. For example one /about route, but it doesn't work.

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var router  = express.Router();

    var moment = require('moment'); 

    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
    var upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data


    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    //some action
    });


    app.get('/time', function (req, res) {
     //...

    });


    app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
        res.send('about');
      });
```

Currently after calling url/about I'm getting `Cannot GET /about` as a return and after some research I've got no idea how to resolve this issue. They even describe it that way in the official express docs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to access the `/` route? and have you `app.listen` a port?

Comment: The `/` works fine. I've also got a `app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});` at the end of the code.

Comment: Just tested your code and ```$ curl http://localhost:3000/about ->
about``` worked

Comment: But on the server it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You have something like this in your code? :

```
app.listen(SERVER_PORT, function () {
console.log("Server successfully started on port:" + SERVER_PORT); });
```

Comment: Yes. It's in the end `app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});`.

Answer (score 0):

We should have something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
const app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/about', routes.about);
```

- and also in the views folder: **about.jade**

Comment: I'm not that sure what this all means. I'm not even rendering anything. It just has to return a JSON Document.